# How to use node modules within a Django app

Tags: javascript, python, django, node-modules

I developed a web map app using Django. I used Leaflet for the map and I'd like to add some Leaflet plugins that are meant to be installed using `npm`. I'm new to node (I've only used it in Development during my classes) and have never used it in Production or with Django.

I'm wondering if I have to configure anything else in my project or if I can just `npm init` and then `npm install anything`. I suppose I'd have to add node_modules to my .gitignore but I'm not sure how should I manage the static files generated by node and how should I import modules into my django templates.

I'd be using Node only for front-end stuff, all my back-end is managed by Django.

I haven't installed anything yet as I'm afraid I'll break my web.

Comment: If you don't want to use package manager, then you don't have to. I would avoid it if you only need it for just a couple leaflet dependencies. You can use the cdn version or download locally and host them on your server. I don't know exactly which leaflets plugin you are trying to add but there would definitely be a cdn version of those as well.